# Dynamic string in the middle of an url NextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have several routes like...

```
/defects
/amenities
/information
```

I need to update it like this below

```
<BUILDING_ID>/defects
<BUILDING_ID>/amenities
<BUILDING_ID>/information
```

for example

```
a83j-782a/defects
a83j-782a/amenities
a83j-782a/information
```

the building id is exist after user logged in

I need to know how to create dynamic url like that in NextJS, so far i didn't found any helpful resources to learn how to do it

Comment: `[buildingId]/defects` where the variable `buildingId` contains the value `a83k-782s` - and this may be used with [`next/router` - dynamic routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes).

Comment: oh @jsN00b i just realize it is that easy, my bad, thanks a lot!